# CSS equally divide white-space between elements but with max-space

Tags: html, css, spacing

I'm creating a navigation `ul` with different `li`, which should be sharing the white-space equally.

The problem is that the white-space between element should have a maximum width of `30px`. The link on the right side should always stay right.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ul {
  margin: 0 30px 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
li:first-child{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.secondPart {
  margin-left:auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <ul>
    <li>my elem</li>
    <li>my elem 2</li>
    <li>my elem 3</li>
    <li>my elem 4</li>
  </ul>
  <div class=secondPart>
    <a>my link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Summarizing the problem:

the `li` should have a dynamic space between elements, but a max-space of `30px`. I added a padding, because that should be the `min-space`.

Would greatly appreciate any hints!

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kLu34f1a/14/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cyo3u6t2/

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 not quite sure how this works, the spacing still grows bigger than 30px?

Answer (score 0):

## Use margin on li, and jQuery to measure the length of child items

This will get you close. I would recommend adding a max-width to your `ul`

The snippet uses jQuery to measure the length of the child items. If the sum of the items is greater than the container width, there is a function to change the margin of the line items. You'll notice the console.log function invokes if you add more `li`'s

I set the margin to 15px on `li`'s (15 on each side for a total of 30 maximum pixels separation)

```js
var containerWidth = $("#li-container").outerWidth();

console.log(containerWidth);

var w = 0;
// the 'true' paramater inside the outerWidth function includes margins
$("#li-container li").each(function(){
  w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});

console.log(w);

// if the total length of the line items is more than the container, do this event
if(w>containerWidth) {

$("#li-container li").each(function(){
$(this).css("margin", "0px 5px");
});

console.log(w);

}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ul {
  margin: 0 30px 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 600px;
}
li {
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
li:first-child{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.secondPart {
  margin-left:auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <ul id="li-container">
    <li>my elem</li>
    <li>my elem 2</li>
    <li>my elem 3</li>
    <li>my elem 4</li>
  </ul>
  <div class=secondPart>
    <a>my link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to solve it without jQuery, if possible :)